# Complex Query where record is max in set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data that looks like this

```
CandidateCategory
candidateCategoryId
candidateId
categoryId
```

I want to return all records where a specific categoryId is the most recent entry, this max(candidateCategoryId)

So if a candidate has 5 categories I want to get that record for say category 23 but only if that is the most recent category added, ie candidateCategoryId is higher than all others for that category.

Using MS SQL 2012

Sample data in format

```
candidateCategoryId  candidateId   categoryId
    100              1             10
    101              1             11
    102              1             50
    103              1             23
    104              1             40
```

no result, 23 isn't the max candidateCategoryId

```
candidateCategoryId  candidateId   categoryId
    200              2             20
    201              2             31
    202              2             12
    203              2             23
```

return result, 23 is the max candidateCategoryId for this candidate.

Comment: It might be helpful to read the question that has the schema, table name and 3 fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this

```
select    candidateCategoryId
from      candidateCategory
where     candidateCategoryId in (
    select    max(candidateCategoryId)
    from      candidateCategory
    group by  candidateId )
and       categoryId = 23
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the max CandidateCategoryID per CandidateID First, then re-join back

```
select
      yd2.*
   from
      ( select yd.candidateID,
               max( yd.candidateCategoryId ) as maxCandCatID
           from YourData yd
           group by yd.candidateID ) MaxPerID
         JOIN YourData yd2
            on MaxPerID.candidateID = yd2.candidateID
           AND MaxPerID.maxCandCatID = yd2.CandidateCategoryID
           AND yd2.categoryID = 23
```

So, from your sample data, the inner prequery "MaxPerID" will generate two rows...

```
CandidateID   MaxCandCatID   (and ultimately corresponds to category ID)
1             104            40
2             203            23
```

Then, re-joining back to your original table on these two inclusive of your AND CategoryID = 23 will only return the second CandidateID entry

And to help clarify to others who posted answers, the person does not appear to want the highest category ID, but if you look at them, they are sequentially added -- like an auto-incrementing number for the CandidateCategoryID.  So, they want the most recent entry for a given candidate (hence candidates 1 & 2)... and if the last entry made was that of category = 23, they want THAT one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic "greatest-of-n" problem.  You can solve it with `not exists`, among other ways:

```
select t.*
from somedata t
where not exists (select 1
                  from somedata t2
                  where t2.categoryId = t.categoryId and
                        t2.candidateCategoryId > t.candidateCategoryId
                 );
```

EDIT:

If you only want categories where the max is 23, then add another condition:

```
select t.*
from somedata t
where not exists (select 1
                  from somedata t2
                  where t2.categoryId = t.categoryId and
                        t2.candidateCategoryId > t.candidateCategoryId
                 ) and
      t.categoryId = 23
```

Comment: How does this check for a specific categoryId like 23 to be the max?

Comment: @DaleFraser . . . Actually, you edited the question and now I'm not sure what you want. This returns the data for the row with the maximum category id.

Comment: I only provided examples as requested, the question always stated for a specific categoryId 23. I only want records where that categoryId is the max id for the candidate.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
  from (select t.*
          from tbl t
          join (select candidateid,
                      categoryid,
                      max(candidatecategoryid) as lastid
                 from tbl
                group by candidateid, categoryid) v
            on t.candidateid = v.candidateid
           and t.categoryid = v.lastid) x
 where categoryid = 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to skin this cat. Using your sample data, we can create an inline table for testing and get

```
DECLARE @candidates TABLE (CandidateCategoryId int,CandidateId int,CategoryId int)

INSERT INTO @candidates 
SELECT 100, 1, 10
UNION
SELECT 101, 1, 11
UNION
SELECT 102, 1, 50
UNION
SELECT 103, 1, 23
UNION
SELECT 104, 1, 40
UNION
SELECT 200, 2, 20
UNION
SELECT 201, 2, 31
UNION
SELECT 202, 2, 12
UNION
SELECT 203, 2, 23

SELECT * FROM @candidates c
JOIN 
(
SELECT CandidateId,MAX(CategoryId) AS CategoryId FROM @candidates
GROUP BY CandidateId
) tmp 
ON c.CandidateId = tmp.CandidateId 
AND c.CategoryId = tmp.CategoryId
```

And get results that look like

```
CandidateCategoryId | CandidateId | CategoryId
----------------------------------------------
201                 |    2        |   31
102                 |    1        |   50
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * 
from  yourtable 
where  candidateCategoryId = (select max(candidateCategoryId) from yourtable)
```

Comment: This would normally return exactly one row.

Comment: true. Trying to read OP's mind. Guess i was using wrong crystal ball

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @categoryId int

select  @categoryId = 23

with cte as
(
    select  candidateCategoryId, candidateId, categoryId,
        rn  = row_number() over (partition by candidateId order by candidateCategoryId  desc)
    from    yourtable
)
select  *
from    cte c
where   exists
(
    select  *
    from    cte x
    where   x.candidateId   = c.candidateId
    and x.rn        = 1
    and x.categoryId    = @categoryId
)
```